# Conditional Statement issue in C++

Tags: c++

Here is the question that I've been trying to solve:

> You are given a positive integer, n,:
>
> If 1 ≤ n ≤ 9, then print the English representation of it. That is "**one**" for 1, "**two**" for 2, and so on.
>
> Otherwise print "**Greater than 9**" (without quotes)

Here is a portion of my suggested answer, but it doesn't work!

```
int n;

if (1 <= n <= 9) {
    if (n == 1) {
    cout << "one" << endl;
    } else if (n == 2) {
    cout << "two" << endl;
    } else if (n == 3) {
    cout << "three" << endl;
    } else if (n == 4) {
    cout << "four" << endl;
    } else if (n == 5) {
    cout << "five" << endl;
    } else if (n == 6) {
    cout << "six" << endl;
    } else if (n == 7) {
    cout << "seven" << endl;
    } else if (n == 8) {
    cout << "eight" << endl;
    } else if (n == 9) {
    cout << "nine" << endl;
    }
} else {
    
    cout << "Greater than 9" << endl;
}
```

What is the issue with the code?

Comment: Well, at least this one's a [mcve]... That's worth an upvote, even to bring it to it's starting point of 0...

Comment: @SamVarshavchik um no it isn't... there's no `main` function

Comment: @M.M  Well, I am ok with cutting a bit of slack like that. This is still much more "complete" than half the questions around here. I don't mind slapping a main() around something, or add a missing #include file. Hey, this one even officially declared its "int n;". Good enough for me.

Comment: Even doing that, this will cause undefined behaviour by using uninitialized variable `n`

Comment: why don't use `switch`?

Answer (score 7):

Change `if (1 <= n <= 9)` to `if (n>= 1 && n<=9)`

Comment: Or `if(1 <= n && n <= 9)`

Comment: It didn't work. I use hackerrank.com to practice for C++, and there is a question I'm facing that problem with. It didn't accept any kind of answer!

Comment: @r.n.m.k have you initialized the variable n?

Answer (score 5):

`if (1 <= n <= 9)` doesn't do what you think it does. It's evaluated as ((1 <= n) <= 9). <= returns a Boolean, so you're checking if 'true' or 'false' is less than 9.

You want to use the 'and' operator, &&.

Answer (score 1):

`if (1 <= n <= 9) {` should be `if (1 <= n && n <= 9) {`

You could also arrive at the solution by using the `switch` statement:

```
//Problem states n is a positive integer, so no need to check if n < 1
switch(n)
{
  case 1: cout << "one" << endl; break;
  case 2: cout << "two" << endl; break;
  //etc...
  case 9: cout << "nine" << endl; break;
  default: cout << "Greater than 9" << endl;
}
```

It does the same thing, but it looks cleaner in my opinion.